# Jersey: UriConnegFilter now declared final, breaks old code: how to fix it?

Tags: jersey

In Jersey 2.15, I was using a class
`public class MyMediaTypeFilter extends UriConnegFilter`
(declared in my web.xml) to return content type corresponding to some extensions (for instance, to return html content when the URL ends with ".html".)

This way of doing a "file extension based content negotiation" seemed to be of common use (it is explained, for instance, in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644622/how-to-create-a-jax-rs-service-where-the-sub-resource-path-doesnt-have-a-leadi))

I just tried to upgrade to Jersey 2.22, and my code doesn't compile anymore, because UriConnegFilter is now declared final.

Is there a simple fix?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

answering my own question (it was easy enough):

instead of extending UriConnegFilter, implement the ContainerRequestFilter interface, using an instance of UriConnegFilter as attribute:

```
@PreMatching
public class MediaTypeFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private UriConnegFilter filter;
    private static final Map<String, MediaType> mappedMediaTypes = new HashMap<String, MediaType>(4);

    static {
        mappedMediaTypes.put("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML_TYPE);
        ...
    }

    public MediaTypeFilter() {
        filter = new UriConnegFilter(mappedMediaTypes, null);
    }

    @Override public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        filter.filter(requestContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the filter is already registered. All you need to do is provide a configuration property with the mappings

```
Map<String, MediaType> mediaTypes = ...
resourceConfig.property(ServerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE_MAPPINGS, mediaTypes);
```

If you're using web.xml (and not a ResourceConfig), you could add a `Feature` instead

```
@Provider
public UrlConnegFeature implements Feature {
    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext ctx) {
        Map<String, MediaType> mappings = ...
        ctx.property(ServerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE_MAPPINGS, mappings);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I didn't succeed (maybe I didn't try hard enough, as I now have something that works :-)) Probably a problem in my web.xml (I'm using jersey as servlet) I registered the UrlConnegFeature among the provider classes (cf `<init-param><param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>`). What else? (in the working solution that I described above, there's also `<init-param><param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>`) Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you are package scanning for all your resources and providers, the Feature should get picked up by the `@Provider` annotation, though you can also specify it in the `...classnames` init-param. The second init-param you mentioned is useless. It is for Jersey 1

Comment: Or if for some reason the filter is not registered, you can explicitly register it, and the also the feature. The point is, trying to extend the filter just to set the property is not the best solution. Just adds another class for no reason

Comment: you are right concerning the `<init-param><param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</p‌​aram-name>` mentionned earlier. Garbage that can be removed.

Comment: I understand your point, and I'd happily follow your suggestion. I imagine that other people will get the same kind of trouble as I got (Jersey having broken backward compatibility, and this use of UriConnegFilter having been recommended in the past). So an easy upgrade for such code would be nice. I checked that the configure method is called, so the provider is found. I'll try to see how to register the filter and the feature.